# capistrano error on cached-copy

Tags: capistrano

I am receiving the following error when running a cap deploy:update

failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/deployer/apps/all_bout_texas/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/deployer/apps/all_bout_texas/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git reset -q --hard 2350e98662e7fe00d526ff5f69460beb868a978a && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q --depth 1 git@github.com:jpowell/all_bout_texas.git /home/deployer/apps/all_bout_texas/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/deployer/apps/all_bout_texas/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 2350e98662e7fe00d526ff5f69460beb868a978a; fi'"

Here is my deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "all_bout_texas"

# If you aren't deploying to /u/apps/#{application} on the target
# servers (which is the default), you can specify the actual location
# via the :deploy_to variable:
set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/apps/#{application}"

# If you aren't using Subversion to manage your source code, specify
# your SCM below:

default_run_options[ty] = true

set :scm, :git

set :repository, "git@github.com:jpowell/all_bout_texas.git"

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :branch, "master"

set :git_shallow_clone, 1

set :copy_cache, true


# abt

role :app, "174.143.241.236"

role :web, "174.143.241.236"

role :db, "174.143.241.236", rimary => true


set :scm_username, "my_user"

set :scm_passphrase, "my_pass"

set :scm_verbose, false


set :user, "my_user"

set :runner, "my_user"


namespace :deploy do

task :copy_database_configuration do

production_db_config = "/home/deployer/config/abt_database.yml"

run "cp #{production_db_config} #{release_path}/config/database.yml"

end


desc "Restarting mod_rails with restart.txt"

task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do

run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"

end


[:start, :stop].each do |t|

desc "#{t} task is a no-op with mod_rails"

task t, :roles => :app do ; end

end


after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:copy_database_configuration"

after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:restart"


end
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-posting is bad taste Josh; you're at risk of wasting the time of two communities, at least have the courtesy to tell one, you posted to the other.

You need to verify (as I posted on the Google list) that your deployment works without using :remote_cache.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I came across this error today when trying to deploy from a github private repo. I was able to fix it by specifying the name of the cache directory I want to use via the little known `repository_cache` option and using underscores instead of hyphens:

`set :repository_cache, "cached_copy"`

If you take a look at the [Capistrano Github repo for the remote_cache strategy](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/remote_cache.rb) then you'll see that it is setting the repository_cache to 'cached-copy'

I created an [issue in the Capistrano Github project](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/64) in case there's any activity on it from the community.